# How do I return in Gremlin only paths which ends with vertices that other paths didn't end with yet?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Let's assume I have the following graph:

```
A->B, B->D
A->C, C->D
A->E
```

I want to return all paths which start from A, but don't include multiple paths which end with the same vertex.
So in case, the result will be:
A->B->D (or A->C->D) and A->E

Since the graph is very big and there can be a lot of paths, if there is an efficient way the engine can prune the paths without collecting all of them first, it is preferable.

Comment: You can look here for inspiration: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#_small_graph_traversals, using a combination of repeat() and aggregate(), the latter for storing end vertices already visited. For saving memory, only store the vertex ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon how cyclic the data in the graph is, this can be an expensive query. I am assuming each eventual target is a leaf node. In such cases, the basic query might end up something like this:

```java
g.V('A').
  repeat(out().simplePath()).
  until(not(out())).
  where(without('x')).store('x').
  path()
```